# Why are Isaac and Rivka in Shochen Ad

Tags: tefilla, avot-patriarch-fathers, song-poetry, shacharis-morning-prayer

Many siddurim capitalize the Yitzchak in Shochen Ad.  Some draw attention to the Rivka.  But why are either of them there?  If you wanted to throw Yitzchak somewhere, why not minchah, which we midrashically derive from him.

> bfi **Y**sharim tit**H**alal
>   uvdivrei **Tz**adikim tit**B**arach
>   uvilshon **Ch**asidim tit**R**omam
>   uv'kerev **K**'doshim tit**K**adash
>
> בְּפִי **יְ**שָׁרִים תִּתְ**הַ**לָּל
>   וּבְדִבְרֵי **צַ**דִּיקִים תִּתְ**בָּ**רַךְ
>   וּבִלְשׁוֹן **חֲ**סִידִים תִּתְ**ר**וֹמָם
>  
>   וּבְקֶרֶב **קְ**דוֹשִׁים תִּתְ**קַ**דָּשׁ

PS. Sorry for the lack of Hebrew - I'm on my work computer and I could only find copyable chol davening.  Feel free to edit / change to the Hebrew / add English.

Comment: That is the N' Ashkenaz version. Other versions switch around the order to make Rivkah clearer. (Incidentally, Ashkenaz also uses the Rivkah-emphasized version for Rosh HaShanah and Yom Kippur.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per [Rabbi Aaron Gamliel in the Sefer Matei Aharon](http://temani.net/nishmat/4.htm), the words Yitzchok & Rivka = Tefila (יצחק רבקה" בגימטריא "תפלה") and per the Raya Mehemna Zohar Chadash Vol 3, page 223:1 & page 253:1 the Shechina is also called Tefila since the whole purpose of Tefila is to connect to Hashem, like the name Naftali (נפתולי אלקים נפתלתי).

In Bereishis 25:21 it says ויעתר יצחק ל**נכח** אשתו כי עקרה היא

The word Nochach is Roshei Teivos נ'שמת כ'ל ח'י, and therefore in Nishmas Yitzchok & Rivka are standing opposite each other since the Posuk finishes that he was immediately answered - 'ויעתר לו ה.

The [Avudram](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=87) says that the name of the composer was Yitzchok and his wife's name was Rivka, and he made it in honor of Yitzchok Avinu and Rivka Imainu.