# Shochen Ad- Isaac & Rivka

Tags: shabbat, avot-patriarch-fathers, yom-kippur, song-poetry, shacharis-morning-prayer

How come (for nusach Ashkenaz) Shochen Ad spells out Isaac & Rivka on Yom Kippur, but only Isaac is spelled on regular shabbos? For Sephardim and nusach Sephard, it always spells out both names.

Furthermore, the ArtScroll commentary for the shabbos Shochen Ad says that Isaac is probably the name of the author, ignoring the potential Rivka connection. Whats up with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Isaac and Rivka in Shochen Ad](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16923/why-are-isaac-and-rivka-in-shochen-ad)

Comment: Not exactly. This questions asks why Rivka is sometimes not there.

Comment: Not a dupe -- this effectively asks "if the reason, as per Artscroll Machzor, p. 263 is that Isaac and Rebecca prayed together and were answered, wouldn't we want to be answered every Shabbat?" Why WOULDN'T Rivka be there all the time?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=179